# iTransact, where do I find my api_username, xid and payload_signature values for creating an HTML subscription form?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

When creating an HTML subscription form for iTransact, where does one find out the values for the following required form fields:

a) api_username
b) xid

The documentation is unclear (http://www.itransact.com/downloads/PCRecurGuide.pdf) and I cannot find any information with the names 'api_username' or 'xid' from within the Account Control Panel when I log into iTransact.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

a) api_username is the same thing that is referred to as "Gateway ID number", "Order Form UID" and "vendor_id" in other places in the documentation.

and

b) xid means "transaction id"